# codeigniter ajax search not work

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with ajax search in my codeigniter project.
The search no show data, and after click SEARCH button page freez 1-2 sec. I think the problem is anywhere in getting the information from the database but, also the model is correct.

There is the code:

Model:

```
var $table = 'users';
 function search($options = array(), $status = true, $limit = null, $offset = 0) {
    $this->db->select('users.username,types.t_title,media.photo');
            $str = '';

    if ($options['username'] != '') {
        $str .= ' AND users.username =' . $this->db->escape($options['username']);
    }

    if (!$status) {
        $str .= ' AND users.active = 1';
    }
    $this->db->where('users.username', 'LIKE', '%' . $options['username'] . '%' . $str);
    $this->db->group_by('users.id');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $search = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $search->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
    public function search($offset = 0) {
 $options = $this->Users->array_from_post(array('username'));
     if ($this->form_validation->run('search')) {
      $count = $this->Property->search($options, $status = FALSE);
      $perpage = 10;
      if (count($count) > $perpage) {
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('welcome/search');
            $config['total_rows'] = count($count);
            $config['per_page'] = $perpage;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
            $q = $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $offset = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        } else {
            $this->data['pagination'] = '';
            $offset = 0;
        }
        $status = 1;

        $this->data['search'] = $this->Users->search($options, $status = FALSE, $perpage, $offset);
        $this->load_search('search');

     }
}
```

And View with ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form[name='search']").submit(function(e) {
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/welcome/search'); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
        $(".search_area").html(msg); 

    },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>



        <form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" name="search">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="input-text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                      </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="search-button" name="search" value="Search">
                    </div>
                </div>
                  </div>
       </form>

 <div class="search_area"> 

 </div>
```

All is connected and load the template, but the only message with `No Record Found`

And here is search view:

```
 <div class="main-title">
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<div class="border">
    <div class="border-inner"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
      <?php if ($search) : ?>
       <?php foreach ($search as $sr): ?>
       <p>Tralalala <?php echo $sr['title']; ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php else:?>
                <div class="notification-box">
                <h3><?php echo $this->lang->line('no_record'); ?></h3>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: why there are two welcome <?php echo site_url('welcome/welcome/search'); ?>, don't you think it should be one

Comment: the controller path is Modules/welcome/controllers/Welcome.php and function is search.

Comment: Try printing $this->data['search']. IF it is giving you quick response then the error will be in load_search

Comment: $this->data['search'] is work... load the template (search)

Comment: Then the error will be in **$this->load_search('search')**

Comment: var_dump($this->data['search']) ;  gives `array(0) { }`

Comment: show load_search method